# conditional sum(sumif) in org-table

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

I have a table like this:

```
#+NAME: ENTRY
|------+--------|
| Item | Amount |
|------+--------|
| A    |    100 |
| B    |     20 |
| A    |    120 |
| C    |     40 |
| B    |     50 |
| A    |     20 |
| C    |     16 |
|------+--------|
```

and then I need to sum each item in another table:

```
#+NAME: RESULT
|------+-----|
| Item | Sum |
|------+-----|
| A    | 240 |
| B    |  70 |
| C    |  56 |
|------+-----|
```

I've tried using vlookup and remote reference in this table, but I'm not able to sum the resulting list like:

```
#+TBLFM: $2=vsum((vconcat (org-lookup-all $1 '(remote(ENTRY,@2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(ENTRY,@2$2..@>$2)))))
```

But it does not give the answer.

So I have to use a place holder to hold the resulting list then sum it:

```
#+NAME: RESULT
|------+--------------+-----|
| Item | Placeholder  | Sum |
|------+--------------+-----|
| A    | [100 120 20] | 240 |
| B    | [20 50]      |  70 |
| C    | [40 16]      |  56 |
|------+--------------+-----|
#+TBLFM: $2='(vconcat (org-lookup-all $1 '(remote(ENTRY,@2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(ENTRY,@2$2..@>$2))))::$3=vsum($2)
```

Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is without `vsum`:

```
#+TBLFM: $2='(apply '+ (mapcar 'string-to-number (org-lookup-all $1 '(remote(ENTRY,@2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(ENTRY,@2$2..@>$2)))))
```

If you want to use a calc function, you can always use `calc-eval`:

```
#+TBLFM: $2='(calc-eval (format "vsum(%s)" (vconcat (org-lookup-all $1 '(remote(ENTRY,@2$1..@>$1)) '(remote(ENTRY,@2$2..@>$2))))))
```